# Unequal margins matrix

Tags: matrices

Why does my matrix have unequal margins(brackets)?

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \begin{document}
    \tiny
        \begin{equation}
        \begin{matrix}
        \left[\rule{0pt}{20pt}\right.\!\!\!\!\!
        &\begin{bmatrix}
        -1.235 & 2.131 & -1.815 & 0.738 & 0.571 & -0.561 & -0.57 
         0.219 & -0.417 & -0.109 & -0.265 & -0.418 & 0.459 & -0.401 
         -0.28 & 1.07 & 1.858 & 2.025 & -1.154 & 0.009 & 1.724 
         -0.255 & 1.146 & -0.327 & -0.108 & 0.347 & -0.739 \end{bmatrix},&\\[18pt]
        &\begin{bmatrix}
        -0.903 & 0.539 & -0.836 & 0.728 & -1.328 & -0.443 & -1.009 
         1.156 & -0.05 & -0.449 & 0.385 & -0.48 & 0.904 & -0.395 
         -2.008 & -0.152 & 0.325 & -0.353 & 0.448 & -0.163 & 1.207 
         -0.167 & 0.413 & -0.627 & -0.556 & 0.018 & -0.276 \end{bmatrix},&\\[18pt]
         \end{matrix}
        \end{equation}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you highlight in the image which two braces you're referring to?

Comment: When compiling your MWE, I do get aligned brackets. (I have added `\\\` at each line end as I suggest, it was missing due to some copy paste error. If not, your MWE is not compilable as is)

Comment: @LaRiFaRi  need 27 columns

Comment: Because column 5 is wider in the 2nd row (with the presence of  the negative sign) and columns 7 and 8 as well.  On the other hand, column 10 is wider in the 1st row.

Comment: Could you explain or draw how that is supposed to look? You screenshot does not show the result of you MWE and it does not show 27 columns.

Comment: I believe all the matrix macros have a 10 column limit.  You might try array.

Comment: @JohnKormylo The limit for matrices is the value of `MaxMatrixCols`, which can be set to any value with `\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{30}` (or whatever so long as it's at least the maximum number of columns one wants).

Comment: @x-rw There is no way you can fit such a beast in standard paper size. Since you get tens of error messages with your input, you should first try and remove them (see my previous comment).

Answer (score 3):

There is no way your 27 item rows can be readable and fit in normal size paper.

My proposal is to pretend the rows continue even if they appear split:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{2.3pt}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \,
  \begin{array}{@{}r *{9}{S[table-format=-1.3]} l@{}}
  [
  &  -1.235 &  2.131 & -1.815 &  0.738 &  0.571 & -0.561 & -0.57  &  0.219 & -0.417 \\
  &  -0.109 & -0.265 & -0.418 &  0.459 & -0.401 & -0.28  &  1.07  &  1.858 &  2.025 \\
  &  -1.154 &  0.009 &  1.724 & -0.255 &  1.146 & -0.327 & -0.108 &  0.347 & -0.739 & ],
  \end{array}
\\ \addlinespace[1ex]
  \begin{array}{@{}r *{9}{S[table-format=-1.3]} l@{}}
  [
  &  -0.903 &  0.539 & -0.836 &  0.728 & -1.328 & -0.443 & -1.009 &  1.156 & -0.05  \\
  &  -0.449 &  0.385 & -0.48  &  0.904 & -0.395 & -2.008 & -0.152 &  0.325 & -0.353 \\
  &   0.448 & -0.163 &  1.207 & -0.167 &  0.413 & -0.627 & -0.556 &  0.018 & -0.276 & ],
  \end{array}
  \,
  \end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following solution (a) typesets two 27-element row vectors and (b) aligns the numbers on their decimal markers across rows. The row vectors are encased in square brackets.

[image]

If you cannot read the numbers above, that's because they were generated with `\tiny` in effect, for a 50% linear reduction in font size relative to the main document font size. Choosing such a small font size was necessary even though the page was set up in landscape format, a very narrow margin was chosen, and the usual amount of whitespace between columns of an `array` environment was reduced by 60% relative to the default. In short: Please reconsider whether it's a good idea to inflict [!] 27-element row vectors on your readers. Which details of these vectors are your readers supposed to remember ten minutes after having across them?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for 'S' column type
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'gather*' environment

\begin{document}
\tiny
\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt} % default: 5pt

\begin{gather*}
[\begin{array}{@{} *{27}{S[table-format=-1.3]} @{}}
-1.235 & 2.131 & -1.815 & 0.738 & 0.571 & -0.561 & -0.57 & 0.219 & -0.417 & -0.109 & -0.265 & -0.418 & 0.459 & -0.401 & -0.28 & 1.07 & 1.858 & 2.025 & -1.154 & 0.009 & 1.724 & -0.255 & 1.146 & -0.327 & -0.108 & 0.347 & -0.739
\end{array}] \\
[\begin{array}{@{} *{27}{S[table-format=-1.3]} @{}}
-0.903 & 0.539 & -0.836 & 0.728 & -1.328 & -0.443 & -1.009 & 1.156 & -0.05 & -0.449 & 0.385 & -0.48 & 0.904 & -0.395 & -2.008 & -0.152 & 0.325 & -0.353 & 0.448 & -0.163 & 1.207 & -0.167 & 0.413 & -0.627 & -0.556 & 0.018 & -0.276
\end{array}]
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```